# Opentok MediaMode::ROUTED alwyas disconnect

Tags: opentok

I have two users who joins a **MediaMode::ROUTED** Session. Both users ***PUBLISHES*** their cameras and microphones and ***SUBSCRIBES*** to the corresponding ***PUBLISHED*** video feed. I'm building a web app that can be used for communication using your Opentok.js.

My current JavaScript codes follows the idea of the AutomaticReconnection (discussed on this URL: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/connect-session/js/#automatic_reconnection).

Note that the users who are testing my codes are in different countries (e.g. in Amsterdam - Netherlands and in the Philippines). Neither of the users triggers the *'disconnect()'* method of the Session - we have a "STOP" button that triggers the *'disconnect()'* Session method. And with several tests that we did, the test users' Session always gets the 'clientDisconnected' event. I have used Tokbox Session Inspector and it has been consistent that I see *'clientDisconnected'* as the cause of our Session disconnection.

Based on the documentation:
"clientDisconnected" — A client disconnected from the session by calling the disconnect() method of the Session object or by closing the browser. ( See Session.disconnect().)

Why do our test users always get 'clientDisconnected' with my MediaMode::ROUTED session? 
What could be the possible cause of this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain this behaviour without more information such as the code you use to connect/publish/subscribe.

It may be easier if you create a TokBox support ticket at https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and include the relevant session ID and connection IDs so the server side logs can be examined.